# Where is the correct place to put adverb in the following sentences

Tags: adverb-placement

Which is correct?

1. He bravely saved his neighbor from a fire.
2. He saved his neighbor bravely from a fire.
3. He saved his neighbor from a fire bravely.

I am wondering where to put "bravely" in the sentences above. Are all of them grammatically correct?

Comment: There are many kinds of adverbs. #1 works best with "bravely" but sounds alien with "yesterday." And this has little to do with grammar. It's usually a question of usage.

Answer (score 1):

Sentence 1 is by far the most natural and most likely to be used by a fluent speaker. Sentences 2 an 3 are not, I would say, grammatically incorrect, but would sound odd to a native speaker.